# Derby Db rows merging

Tags: sql, derby

I have following derby sql statement:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT MEETINGS.MEETING_ID,
        MEETINGS.TITLE,
        RECORDING_FRAME.STARTTIME,
        RECORDING_FRAME.ENDTIME,
        {
                fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND,
                RECORDING_FRAME.STARTTIME,
                RECORDING_FRAME.ENDTIME)
        } AS RUNTIMEFIELD_SESSIONDURATION
FROM APP.MEETINGS
JOIN APP.RECORDING ON
        MEETINGS.MEETING_ID=RECORDING.MEETINGID
JOIN APP.RECORDING_TRACK ON
        RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=RECORDING_TRACK.RECORDING_ID
JOIN APP.RECORDING_FRAME ON
        RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=RECORDING_FRAME.RECORDING_ID
WHERE RECORDING_FRAME.MODULE LIKE 'Recorder' AND
        MEETINGS.STATUS LIKE 'ENDED'
```

If I execute this query, I get following results:

```
MEETING_ID  TITLE                 STARTTIME            ENDTIME              RUNTIMEFIELD_SESSIONDURATION  
----------  --------------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------------------------  
65536       abc                   2013-03-06 21:28:49  (null)               (null)                        
65536       abc                   (null)               2013-03-06 21:30:04  (null)                        
65537       fasfasf               2013-03-06 21:13:13  (null)               (null)                        
65537       fasfasf               (null)               2013-03-06 21:13:40  (null)                        
360448      fasfffa               2013-03-06 21:31:07  (null)               (null)                        
360448      fasfffa               (null)               2013-03-06 21:38:13  (null)                        
360448      fasfffa               (null)               (null)               (null)                        
360450      test                  2013-03-06 22:07:31  (null)               (null)                        
360450      test                  (null)               2013-03-06 22:14:13  (null)                        
1605632     test benno            2013-03-19 18:21:03  (null)               (null)                        
1605632     test benno            (null)               2013-03-19 18:28:02  (null)                        
1605632     test benno            (null)               (null)               (null)                        
3211281     Conference Unni       2013-03-28 11:03:34  (null)               (null)                        
3211281     Conference Unni       (null)               2013-03-28 11:12:49  (null)                        
3211281     Conference Unni       (null)               (null)               (null)                        
3211283     test                  2013-03-28 10:51:27  (null)               (null)                        
3211283     test                  (null)               2013-03-28 10:59:13  (null)                        
3211283     test                  (null)               (null)               (null)                        
3211284     test (Copy)           2013-03-28 11:02:57  (null)               (null)                        
3211284     test (Copy)           (null)               2013-03-28 11:03:08  (null)                        
3211285     test (Copy) (Kopie)   2013-03-28 18:24:35  (null)               (null)                        
3211285     test (Copy) (Kopie)   (null)               2013-03-28 18:24:58  (null)                        
3211288     ss test               2013-03-28 17:02:20  (null)               (null)                        
3211288     ss test               (null)               2013-03-28 17:34:33  (null)                        
3211288     ss test               (null)               (null)               (null)
```

Now, it is obvious that same event (for example, event "abc") from this listing has two records, starttime and endtime. How do I modify this derby sql statement, so it will return for event "abc" starttime and endtime in single row?

Comment: Are we guaranteed that there will be only 1 start and only 1 end for each event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, it seems that table RECORDING_FRAME has 2 or 3 rows that are joined with RECORDING_TRACK on RECORDING_ID. One row has starttime not null, but endtime null, one row has starttime null but endtime not null, and some recordings also have a third row with starttime and endtime null. What you need to do is convert the union (multiple rows) to a join (single row). Here's how you do it:

First create a view of RECORDING_FRAME that contains only the rows where starttime is not null.

```
Create view APP.VW_RF_START as
 (Select RECORDING_ID, STARTTIME from RECORDING_FRAME
  where STARTTIME is not null)
```

Now create a view that contains only the records of RECORDING_FRAME where endtime is not null.

```
Create view APP.VW_RF_END as
 (Select RECORDING_ID, STARTTIME from RECORDING_FRAME
  where ENDTIME is not null)
```

Now if you join the two views on recording_id, you have starttime and endtime in the same row.
And your query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 MEETINGS.MEETING_ID, MEETINGS.TITLE,
 VW_RF_START.STARTTIME, VW_RF_END.STARTTIME,
 {
            fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND,
            RECORDING_FRAME.STARTTIME,
            RECORDING_FRAME.ENDTIME)
 } AS RUNTIMEFIELD_SESSIONDURATION
FROM APP.MEETINGS
JOIN APP.RECORDING ON
    MEETINGS.MEETING_ID=RECORDING.MEETINGID
JOIN APP.RECORDING_TRACK ON
    RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=RECORDING_TRACK.RECORDING_ID
JOIN APP.VW_RF_START ON
    RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=VW_RF_START.RECORDING_ID
JOIN APP.VW_RF_END ON
    RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=VW_RF_START.RECORDING_ID
```

WHERE RECORDING_FRAME.MODULE LIKE 'Recorder' AND
        MEETINGS.STATUS LIKE 'ENDED'

If you can't create the views, then you can define them in the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 MEETINGS.MEETING_ID, MEETINGS.TITLE,
 VW_RF_START.STARTTIME, VW_RF_END.STARTTIME,
 {
            fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND,
            RECORDING_FRAME.STARTTIME,
            RECORDING_FRAME.ENDTIME)
 } AS RUNTIMEFIELD_SESSIONDURATION
FROM APP.MEETINGS
APP.RECORDING ON
    MEETINGS.MEETING_ID=RECORDING.MEETINGID
JOIN APP.RECORDING_TRACK ON
    RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=RECORDING_TRACK.RECORDING_ID
JOIN 
  (Select RECORDING_ID, STARTTIME from RECORDING_FRAME
  where ENDTIME is not null) as VW_RF_START
ON
    RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=VW_RF_START.RECORDING_ID
JOIN 
  (Select RECORDING_ID, STARTTIME from RECORDING_FRAME
  where ENDTIME is not null) as APP.VW_RF_END 
ON RECORDING.RECORDING_ID=VW_RF_START.RECORDING_ID
WHERE RECORDING_FRAME.MODULE LIKE 'Recorder' AND
    MEETINGS.STATUS LIKE 'ENDED'
```

Comment: I am not allowed to changed database (by creating a view, otherwise, super idea!)

Comment: It's not necessary to create view. The view can be inside the query. I edit to include the option.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `DISTINCT` use `GROUP BY` with `MAX(start)` and `MAX(end)`:

Your query will be like this:

```
SELECT id, title, MAX(start), MAX(end)
FROM ....
JOIN...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY id, title
```

Since aggregate functions skip `NULL`s and you **have only 1 start and end** for each event, `MAX` will yield the right result.

**EDIT: With duration calculation**

```
SELECT minmax.*, 
        {
          fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND,
                minmax.StartTime,
                minmax.EndTime)
        } AS RUNTIMEFIELD_SESSIONDURATION
FROM 
    (SELECT id, title, MAX(start) As StartTime, MAX(end) As EndTime
    FROM ....
    JOIN...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY id, title) minmax
```

Table Sub-query section from Derby docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/

Comment: I get only one row (it is merged) - there is too little data and RUNTIMEFIELD_SESSIONDURATION is still null!

Comment: I did it now, thanks man! I've commented that function for duration calculation (will do it in Java) and added GROUP BY MEETINGS.TITLE and it works now!

Comment: God damn! Now I have to filter records by interval between DATEFROM and DATETO and I update WHERE clause and I get no records again!

Comment: You can still use your duration function if you turn your current query into **sub-query** and have you duration calculated in the main query.  If you have problems, please let me know and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I've included query with `duration` with my answer.